# cakePhp and multi languages

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I am creating a website in cakePhp 2.2. I am very new to this framework. I need a help, step by step how to create multilanguage page. I have created translations in Locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES.default.po and the same for fre. What's next? Where can I set language to display? Where can I write language to be displayed for the user?

Thank for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to:
create files and folder as follows:

```
/app/Locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (English)
/app/Locale/fre/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (French)
```

In default.po files you need to create pairs:

```
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "EN Translation"
```

With this, every Hello word will be replaced with EN Translation.

Next you have to set your language i.e.

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fre');
```

If you want to set language for your page, paste this in bootstrap file, if you want to change it during exploring webpage paste this:

```
$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'fre');
```

in beforeFilter function in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [pretty good guide in the CakePHP Cookbook.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)

> To set the language for the current user, you can store the setting in
>   the Session object, like this:
>
> ```
> $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'fre');
> ```
>
> At the beginning of each request in your controller’s beforeFilter you
>   should configure Configure as well:
>
> ```
> class AppController extends Controller {
>     public function beforeFilter() {
>         Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Step by step website Internationalization or Multi language in cakePHP 2+**

Just Follow the steps:

Step 1. How can  Cakephp catch string which need Multilanguage?

Step 2: Create pot file for insert string in different language.

Step 3: Add below code in app/Config/routes.php

Step 4:  Set default language in app/Config/core.php

Step 6: add helper and Cookie component in app/Controller/AppController.php

Step 7: add a method in app/Controller/AppController.php

Step 7: call  _setLanguage(); under  beforeFilter() in  app/Controller/AppController.php

Step 8:  add the links to the languages:

Link will be 
 http://saidul.songzog.com/blog/details/874/step-by-step-website-internationalization-or-multi-language-in-cakephp-2